# Find equation of line through two points (1,3,-4) and (3,2,1)

Tags: linear-algebra

Find equation of the line through two points $(1, 3, -4)$ and $(3, 2, 1)$

I know the correct answer is $[3, 2, 1] + t[2, -1, 5]$

but according to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlRagTNGBF0) the answer should be the first point $[1, 3, -4] + t[2, -1, 5]$

Does it matter which point I use?

Comment: does not matter

Comment: Just to be picky... the equation is not $[3, 2, 1] + t[2, -1, 5]$.  This is not an equation at all because it doesn't have an equals sign.  The equation is actually $[x,y,z]=[3, 2, 1] + t[2, -1, 5]$.

Comment: There’s no such thing as _the_ equation of a line.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. If the line is going through both points, it doesn't matter which is your starting.

$[3, 2, 1] + t_1[2, -1, 5]$

$[1, 3, -4] + t_2[2, -1, 5]$

To show these are equivalent consider $t_2=t_1+1$ then

$[1, 3, -4] + t_2[2, -1, 5] = [1, 3, -4] + (t_1+1)[2, -1, 5] = [1, 3, -4] + t_1[2, -1, 5] + [2, -1, 5] = [3, 2, 1] + t_1[2, -1, 5]$

Comment: @Leucippus Actually it does answer the question "does it matter which point I use?"

Comment: It does in fact answer the question.  Answerer is encouraged to expand his answer showing why the two lines are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Take the difference of the two vectors (to get the direction vector),  and use either point to parametrize the line:  $\{(1,3,-4)+t(2,-1,5):  t\in\Bbb R\}=\{(3,2,1)+t(2,-1,5):  t\in\Bbb R\}$.